# Cypress class name query returns wrong class name?

Tags: ui-automation, cypress

I'm working on a test right now that checks whether a dom element's (Front Panel's) class name changes after a certain dom element is clicked. I grab the initial class name of Front Panel, then click the necessary dom element, then query again for the Front Panel class name.  Although I can clearly see a different class name in the browser, Cypress returns the initial class name of Front Panel once again.  What am I missing here?

```
  it('Changes Panel Background Color', () => {
    cy.get('#Front_panel')
      .invoke('attr', 'class')
      .then(prevClassName => {
        cy.get('#color_picker')
          .children()
          .first()
          .children()
          .first()
          .children()
          .first()
          .children()
          .first()
          .children()
          .first()
          .click()

        cy.get('#Front_panel')
          .invoke('attr', 'class')
          .then(newClassName => {
            assert(prevClassName !== newClassName)
          })
      })
  })
```

btw I know this is probably not Cypress best practice ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have a test which works fine for this kind of behavior in my case is for check if a modal show fine. Try something this:

```
  cy.log('has a info button');
  cy.get('.home-header-info-button').click();
  cy.get('.modal-header').should('contain', 'Health Details');
  cy.get('.modal-body-health-info-name').should('contain', 'Tony');
  cy.get('.modal-body-health-info-operator').should('contain', 'Doctor');
  cy.get('.modal-body-info').should('be.visible');
  cy.get('.modal-body-image').should('be.visible');
  cy.get('.modal-footer').should('be.visible');
  cy.get('.modal-header-close').click();
  cy.get('.modal-header').should('not.exist');
```

Is a better practice navigate into your class names, because will be more descriptive and readable for who read this test in another time.